# How can I get the response to a request in a CakePHP Integration Test?

Tags: cakephp, phpunit, integration-testing

We're looking at moving our Integration Tests for our API to CakePHP's version of PHPUnit. We need to test that the returned values from the API are sane (valid JSON, etc...)

The helper methods on the IntegrationTestCase abstract class look really useful, allowing me to simulate requests by simply calling `$this->get('/articles')` or similar, but from what I can tell there's no way to actually read the response to one of these requests. Am I missing something?

It seems that without the helper methods provided by IntegrationTestCase it would be much harder to make requests. So what's my best option here?

Comment: $this->_sendJson($response);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just realised that I can do this by simply accessing `$this->_response`. At first I didn't think I could do this because its visibility is protected, but then I realised that I can access it because my test inherits from IntegrationTestCase.

Comment: Yep ;) It is always good to take a look into the source code, this reveals these things easily.